# Laravel cashier webhook

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks, laravel-cashier

I was wonder if someone could help point in the right direction with laravels cashier (stripe) webhook.

I want to be able to update a column in the subscription database. I have tried over riding the webhook like the laravel documentation says however i believe what i am trying do isnt going to work because the route is using post when I need to use put/patch.

My code below what i have put in the override controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\FrontEnd;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController;

class StripeWebHookController extends WebHookController
{
 public function handleCustomerSubscriptionDeleted( array $payload )
{
  $user = $this->getUserByStripeId($payload['data']['object']['customer']);
    if ($user) {
        $user->subscriptions->filter(function ($subscription) use ($payload) {
         return $subscription->stripe_id === $payload['data']['object']['id'];
        })->each(function ($subscription) {
            $sub = Subscription::where('stripe_id', $subscription->stripe_id)->update([
                    'url' => '',
                ]);
                $subscription->markAsCancelled();
            });
        }

        return new Response('Webhook Handled', 200);

    }
}
```

so how can i go about doing what i want to do when the event is fired from stripes webhook.
Thanks

Comment: Is this your code, or the standard Laravel Cashier code? What's not working? What error do you get? Does `$this->getUserByStripeId()` return the `$user` with all their subscriptions preloaded? What does `$subscription->markAsCancelled()` do?

Comment: Hey fubar! I copied this code from the standard webhook and created a custom webhook controller. Only difference is the subscription model/update method. The hook works as the Stripe sends subscription updates. It's just my subscription update isn't being run. How can I debug it? The code runs based on the event Stripe updates automatically.

Comment: Can any one help me with this? I am still stuck and haven't found a solution to this issue :( thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

So someone pointed out i wasn't importing the model for subscription :/ . Now its working as expected.